# GADTs in Haskell with map and filter functions

Tags: haskell, generics, functional-programming, recursive-datastructures, gadt

I'm working with Algebraic DataType in Haskell. I would like to define a recursive structure with functions that could modify the type of the data. Y read about *GADTs* and I think It could help me with the problem, but I'm stuck.

I'm designin an execution graph where every "Node" of execution (what I call "Rdd") is a function applied to a specific data. So, I can have only data (*PlainData*), a map function (*Map*) to apply to the data, a Cartesian Product (*Cartesian*) between two Rdd or a *Filter*. Its logic is like a pipe where I can define the data, and apply one or more adjacent operations.

I have the following code:

```
data Rdd a where
    PlainData :: [a] -> Rdd a
    Map :: (a -> b) -> (Rdd a) -> (Rdd b)
    Cartesian :: (Rdd a) -> (Rdd a) -> (Rdd b)
    Filter :: (a -> Bool) -> (Rdd a) -> (Rdd a)

totalEvaluate :: Rdd a -> b
totalEvaluate (PlainData xs) = xs -- [a]
totalEvaluate (Map f e1) = map f (totalEvaluate e1) -- Rdd b
totalEvaluate (Filter f e1) = filter f (totalEvaluate e1) -- Rdd a
totalEvaluate (Cartesian e1 e2) = [(x, y) | x <- (totalEvaluate e1), y <- (totalEvaluate e2)] -- A tuple with all combinations
```

It's throwing type errors. I would like to be able to execute functions like this one:

```
totalEvaluate (Map (\x -> x + 1) (PlainData [1, 2, 3])) -- [2, 3, 4] It does not change the type
totalEvaluate (Map (\x -> x < 2) (PlainData [1, 2, 3])) -- [True, False, False] It changes the type
totalEvaluate (Cartesian (PlainData [1, 2]) (PlainData[3, 4, 5])) -- [(1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)] It changes the type
totalEvaluate (Filter (\(x, y) -> (y - x) == 2) (Cartesian (PlainData [1, 2]) (PlainData[3, 4, 5]))) -- [(1, 3), (2, 4)] It changes the type
```

I'm following the [Haskell's wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT) but It's not working as It's throwing types error like:

> Couldn't match expected type ‘b’ with actual type ‘[(a0, b0)]’

I'm running the example with:

```
ghci
:l "example.hs"
```

Thanks in advance and sorry about my English

Comment: Could you perhaps describe what you are trying to achieve with this function? There are multiple type errors in the definition (as GHC told you), and in particular the type signature is incredibly (probably impossibly) general, as it says you can get *any* type whatsoever out of this function. That in itself definitely isn't true of your definition.

Comment: On second glance, a type signature of `Rdd a -> [a]` is probably what you want - but there is definitely something wrong with the `Cartesian` constructor. I would assume you want that to have type `Rdd a -> Rdd b -> Rdd (a,b)`

Comment: `Cartesian :: (Rdd a) -> (Rdd a) -> (Rdd b)` looks quite wrong, it states that the result type is completely unrelated to the arguments type (apart from `Rdd`). Surely that's a typo?

Comment: What a shame... I've edited the question with more information about the problem. But changing *Cartesian* type to `(Rdd a) -> (Rdd a) -> (Rdd (a, a))` and the `totalEvaluate` function's type to `Rdd a -> [a]` make it works. Thank you so much and sorry for the time lost

Comment: @Genarito, I suspect it will also work with the more general type `Cartesian :: Rdd a -> Rdd b -> Rdd (a,b)`, which allows the data from each multiplicand to be of different types.

Comment: Thank you so much @luqui. I've edited the code and It worked. If any of you wants to write an answer to close the question I'll mark It as the correct one. Otherwise I'll submit an answer with your corrections later